# How to build this table optimally, skills per user based on another table

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have a question which I have "writers" block on.  I am building a database for a web-app in Mysql.  I have two tables, we'll call them users and jobs.  I want to have another table , lets call it skills.  Now what I'm wanting is a way to link users to skills they have, and another way to link jobs to those same set of skills.  The only way I can think to do this while keeping everything normalized is to basically have an entire list of jobs on each user AND on each job.  Of course this is terrible and isn't acceptable to me, not to mention add skills or removing skills in the future would be a nightmare.

So how would I go about doing this? The only thing I must have is a users table (key ID UserID), Jobs table (Key ID JobId) and a skills table (Key Id skillID), I cannot seem to come up with a solution adding tables\rows\or columns and I'm definitely seeking an answer from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the tables, that is, whatever you have tried yet?

Comment: I really do not know how to format them into text for a visualization.

Comment: You could draw it on a paper and embed an image/provide its link.

Comment: http://imgur.com/QYJhd2O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full answer, expanding on the reply by @shmosel .

Have a table of users and skills, and another table of jobs and skills.

You can then CROSS JOIN the users and jobs to get every combination (narrow it down in the WHERE clause if required), and LEFT OUTER JOIN the jobs / skills table to the jobs. This gives you every combination of jobs and users with the skills required for that job. The LEFT OUTER JOIN the users / skills table to the users table AND to the jobs / skills table.

GROUP BY the user and job, and count the distinct skills on the jobs / skills table, and count the distinct skills on the users / skills table.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT u.fname,
        j.jobname,
        COUNT(DISTINCT js.skillid),
        COUNT(DISTINCT us.skillid),
        (COUNT(DISTINCT us.skillid) / COUNT(DISTINCT js.skillid)) * 100 AS match_percent
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN jobs j
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_skills js  ON j.jobid = js.jobid
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_skills us ON u.userid = us.userid AND js.skillid = us.skillid
GROUP BY u.fname,
        j.jobname
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d30d/1

Comment: Thank you very much, I really don't know why I didn't see it this way, it's elegantly simple.  I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need two additional mapping tables: `user_skills` would have `UserID` and `SkillID`, using their unique combination as a (primary) key. Similarly, `job_skills` would `JobID` and `SkillID`, again with a combined unique key. With that schema in place, any data you need is a simple query away.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how that would work, because if I use the skills as a column then I can't query for them can I? For example user has
userId-other colums
Skills has 
Skill ID + Name
UserSkill has 
UserId-and a LIST Of skills (users not limited to ONE skill) so I can't figure out how to do this, because I do NOT want to use List inside of talbes.

Comment: This is the conclusion I came too, however the skills need be linked many to many (People have more than 1 skill, and jobs can require more than 1 skill) and the only thing I can think of is a list...which isn't a solution at all because it breaks so many things.

Comment: You would have mutlple rows on the user_skills table, one row for each combination of user and skill. 2 columns, with the unique key being over both columns. You can easily search all the skills for a user, or all the users for a skill. Same for the job_skills table. On the limited info you have given I cannot see how this solution won't work.

Comment: Here is a crude picture of what I have now.  http://imgur.com/QYJhd2O    What I want is a table that I can use for users that use's the userId(key) to list out skills as binary, and the same thing for jobs, so that a search can be done quickly to see what users match what jobs.  Also want it built independently so if skills are added later, it doesn't break the system.

Comment: In your example where a job requires skills 1, 2, 5 & 8 and a user only has skills 1, 2 & 8, I take it you would not want that user returned?

Comment: Actually what I want is a way to return a percentage match (But we can do that in php, I just want the tables properly built)

Comment: @DavidMoore This is exactly how a many-to-many is done. You create an intermediate mapping table to define each combination of keys without having to repeat their associated data.